# Is there a way to run js code in the console of a desired website?

Tags: javascript, python, html

For a while now I've been looking for a way to run a couple commands in the js console of a website (I'm using chrome if that helps). I haven't been able to find anything useful. My idea is to have some sort of script (ideally in python) access the dev console of a website and run a couple lines of code to fill in a html form. The whole point is to be able to fill out the form and get the POST response so if theres a better way to do this please let me know.

Comment: Yes, you can do it manually? Or automatically when the page loads, with a userscript. Or without even going to the page, with Puppeteer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to become acquainted with Puppeteer.

Puppeteer Documentation - https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/

Boilerplate -

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
  // other actions...
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Nodejs/Puppeteer/Javascript/Asynchronous/CSS Selectors are concepts/ideas you need to research in tandem to accomplish your task.